# How to get the item from the list based multiple conditions ( like prioritized querying) in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

How to get the item from the list based multiple conditions like prioritized querying in java?

```
List<Employee> employees = List.of(new Employee(1, "AA"), new Employee(2, "BB"), new Employee(3, "CC"), new Employee(4, "DD")), new Employee(4, "EE")), new Employee(4, "FF"));
```

I need to get the employee based on name,

```
Employee emp = null;

for (Employee e : employees) {
   if (e.getName().equals("AA")) {
      emp = e;
   }
}

if (emp == null) {
   for (Employee e : employees) {
     if (e.getName().equals("BB")) {
        emp = e;
     }
  }
}

if (emp == null) {
   for (Employee e : employees) {
      if (e.getName().equals("DD")) {
        emp = e;
     }
   }
 }
```

If `AA` is present in the list then return `AA`, if not then return `BB` if not then return `DD`.

Note: List is not `sorted`. and the if statement can be any word/string.

How to simplify the above code in java?

Comment: What this code is doing? The last loop will override your previous assignments?

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple employees or a single employee? Your code seems to be getting `'AA'` (if found), and then looking for `'BB'` without doing anything with the former. Same for `'BB'` and `'DD'`

Comment: Sorry, missed if-statement. Edited my question

Comment: Still there is quite a lot wrong here. This code is nowhere near compilable. `e.getName` should be `e.getName()`. The "name" is most likely a `String` so you have to use double quotes instead of single quotes (which are for characters). -> `"AA"` instead of `'AA'`. Putting these errors aside, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need not just a filtering but something like prioritized querying I would approach with **Collector**s.

Your main code would look like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> employees = List.of(
            new Employee(4, "EE"),
            new Employee(2, "BB"),
            new Employee(3, "CC"),
            new Employee(1, "AA"),
            new Employee(4, "DD"),
            new Employee(4, "FF")
    );

    System.out.printf(employees
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                            new EmployeeCollector("BB", "AA")).toString());

}
```

And your custom collector would look like this:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class EmployeeCollector implements Collector<Employee, Employee[], Employee> {

    List<String> priorities;

    public EmployeeCollector(String... priorities){
        this.priorities = Arrays.asList(priorities);
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Employee[]> supplier() {
        return () -> new Employee[1];
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Employee[], Employee> accumulator() {
        return (employees, employee) -> {
            if(!isFirstPreferableOverSecond(employees[0], employee)){
                employees[0] = employee;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Employee[]> combiner() {
        return (employees, employees2) -> {
            if(!isFirstPreferableOverSecond(employees[0], employees2[0])){
                employees[0] = employees2[0];
            }
            return employees;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Employee[], Employee> finisher() {
        return employees -> employees[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        Set<Characteristics> characteristics = new HashSet<>();
        characteristics.add(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
        return characteristics;
    }

    boolean isFirstPreferableOverSecond(Employee first, Employee second){
        if(first == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(second != null){
            if(priorities.indexOf(second.getName()) == -1){
                return true;
            }else{
                if(priorities.indexOf(first.getName()) == -1){
                    return false;
                }
                return priorities.indexOf(first.getName()) < priorities.indexOf(second.getName()) ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```